# Zend_Form giving Fatal Error

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, fatal-error

I recently started to work on Zend Framework2 . Everthing going fine but once i used  "$form = new Zend_Form; " to insert new form element i am getting Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form' not found . From the search i came out know that i have to set include_path of  Zend_Framework library but after doing that i am getting the same error message:

I have set this library in Environment Variables and PHP.ini..

**PHP.INI**
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\ZENDPROJECTFOLDER\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend"

**Environmental Variables**
;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\ZENDPROJECTFOLDER\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend

early help it will be appreciable.

Comment: The instructions you've tried from your search have led you to Zend Framework 1 solutions. If you're using Zend Framework 2, maybe start with the guide for the current version -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.2.0/